# need help converting HQL query to LINQ to Objects

Tags: hql, linq-to-objects

Here is my HQL query:

select p, pp, pp.Mrn, pp.Name from PatientProfile pp left join pp.Patient p where pp.Name.FamilyName like firefly%

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    List<PatientProfile> profiles = new List<PatientProfile>();

    var result =
        from pp in profiles
        where pp.Name.FamilyName.StartsWith("firefly")
        select new
                   {
                       Patient = pp.Patient, 
                       PatientProfile = pp, 
                       Mrn = pp.Mrn, 
                       Name = pp.Name
                   };
```

We don't know much about your classes, so if it isn't what you're looking for please post your Patient and PatientProfile properties.